# xcode swift ios subView alpha not working when called from instance

Tags: ios, swift, instance, alpha, subview

I'm having trouble controlling the alpha value of a subview from an instance of another view controller.

Here is some psuedo code of the problem:

```
class FirstView() // TabVC
{
    func hideSecondViewSubView()
    {
        let secondView = SecondView()
        secondView.number = 0 // this value changes correctly
        secondView.subView.alpha = 0.0  // this fails to control the subview alpha
    }        
}

class SecondView() // a tab view
{
    func viewDidLoad()
    {
       addSubview(subView)
    }

    lazy var subView()
    {
        let view = UIView()
        var number = 1  // initial value for test var
        view.alpha = 1.0   // initial alpha for subview 
    }     
}
```

Using Xcode 9.2 on Sierra on an IOS tabbed view project.

Any ideas why this fails?

Comment: You write: *"class FirstView() // TabVC"* ... do you mean `FirstView` is a *subclass* of `UITabViewController`? Or do you mean `FirstView` is the view controller being displayed in the first Tab position?

Comment: And... *"fails to blacken the subview"* ... are you trying to make the subview **BLACK**? Or are you trying to make it transparent?

Comment: FirstView is subclass of UiTabViewController. SecondClass is being displayed in a tab position.

Comment: @DonMag want to turn alpha off

Comment: OK - you need to show a bit more code. Where are you calling `secondView.subView.alpha = 0.0`? On a tab change? On load? Where do you have `subView` defined? And where / when is it being added to SecondView?

Comment: @DonMag, I have edited the original question... 
  to explain further:  secondView.subview.alpha = 0.0 is being called by a button inside of FirstView(). subView is defined inside of SecondView() and called during SecondView's viewDidLoad()

Comment: OK - so, `FirstView` is ***not*** a subclassed `UITabBarController`? Because you wouldn't have a button inside a TabBarController - so it sounds like `FirstView` is the controller that is shown in the first Tab? It matters, because the way your code is shown, what you are describing doesn't make sense.

Comment: As a side note, when asking a question it is best to fully explain what you're trying to do, rather than posting "pseudo code" of what you *think* is the problem. See: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: FirstView IS the UITabBarController and has it's own subView's that are persistent across all tabs.  There is an area on the left side of the display that changes with each tab selection - and THAT small view is the SecondView.   What I was trying to do was to control the alpha of a subView that lives inside of SecondView from within FirstView.

Answer (score 0):

***IF*** this is your actual code...

```
1. class FirstView() // TabVC
2. {
3.     func hideSecondViewSubView()
4.     {
5.         let secondView = SecondView()
6.         secondView.number = 0 // this value changes correctly
7.         secondView.subView.alpha = 0.0  // this fails to control the subview alpha
8.     }        
9. }
```

At line 5, you create a **new** instance of `SecondView`. You then set two properties in the local instance `secondView`.

At line 8, the function exits, the local instance of `secondView` goes out-of-scope, and that `secondView` ***no longer exists***.

If you want to change a value / property in an instance of `SecondView` that was created elsewhere, you must get a reference to ***that*** instance.

So, for example, your class could look similar to this:

```
class FirstView() // TabVC
{
    var secondView = SecondView()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.addSubview(secondView)
        // set initial properties of secondView - constraints, etc.
    }

    func hideSecondViewSubView()
    {
        // don't create a new instance - use the class-scoped instance
        //let secondView = SecondView()
        secondView.number = 0
        secondView.subView.alpha = 0.0
    }        
}
```

If this is *not* the problem, then you really need to post your actual code so we can see what's going on.

Comment: I'll do that... but the last time I did, everyone complained it was too much code (SMH!)

Answer (score -1):

You need to add that into first view as child view than try to change alpha values of parent view, child view values will change automatically.

Comment: Is this true for a TabVC?

Comment: In VC with view it works fine. but in tabVC i didn't tried.(may be tabVC has other view layers.). you should try it.